# Adding Action Bar to Bottom of Screen using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an action bar with a group of 4 buttons to the bottom centre of the screen for my website. I am however having trouble in making the buttons scale correctly as they need to be perfect squares even when changing the size of the window. I have set the width to a percentage, however I cannot do the same with the height, since that will result in the buttons not being perfectly square. Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/38jxwf28/

```
#actionBar {
 position:absolute;
 width:50%;
 height:0%;
 padding-bottom:5%;
 bottom:0px;
 right:25%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Questions: 1) What's the purpose of your `margin-left` style?; 2) Should the buttons wrap to a second line like they do in your fiddle?; 3) Are you looking for a CSS-only solution, or is JavaScript an option?

Comment: I put margin left to attempt to correct the problem where the buttons were not displaying in-line. The buttons should be on the same line in the centre. Both css or javascript are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the buttons to always appear on the screen, I recommend using fixed instead of absolute positioning:

```
#actionBar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

I used 5px for the bottom position to give the buttons a little "breathing" room.

Your buttons wrap because the browser adds a space between elements that are on separate lines.  You can fix that by giving them a "left" float.:

```
button {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  color:#fff;
  border: none;
  background: #109bce;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I added a margin style, again to give them breathing room.

Using JavaScript, we can dynamically determine the width of the buttons, and then use that as `actionBar`'s height:

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var height= b[0].clientWidth;
var bar= document.getElementById('actionBar');
bar.style.height= height+'px';
```

This solves the problem of the squares, but it screws up if you resize the window.  You can resolve that by putting the code in a resize event:

```
window.onresize= function() {
  var b = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var height= b[0].clientWidth;
  var bar= document.getElementById('actionBar');
  bar.style.height= height+'px';
}

window.onresize();
```

### Fiddle